# Prey on Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04 takes a proper picture from the camera, but gives the same screenshot every time

Tags: screenshot

I've recently downloaded PreyProject to my PC, and to my surprise, this is working perfectly, the software is successfully taking pictures from my PC camera, but the screenshot remains the same, every time the computer takes a new picture.

I found out that after rebooting the PC, the first picture will be the correct one, that shows the correct popups that's opening on boot, but all subsequent pictures will be identical to the first picture that Prey took.

***This is a snap installation.***

Any idea how to fix this?
Any suggest will help :)

Comment: is this the deb or snap version? Please [edit] your question accordingly. Reviews suggest there are problems with this package - have you read them?

Comment: @24601 what reviews?
And I've edit my question accordingly, thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: The reviews in the ubuntu software center for that package

Comment: Yes, I've seen them, and now the prey is working perfect
Thank you for your help :)
@24601